# Bamboo older version how to run javascript tests

Tags: javascript, jasmine, bamboo

Is it possible to run tests written in javascript(Jasmine) on an older version of bamboo which doesn't support "Bamboo Node.js" plugin? Is there any other option to run a server there, while doing CI?

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to do from script, then it's possible to run in Bamboo. Node.js plugin is just a wrapper around Node application